# Project location already exists in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I try to create a new flutter project in android studio, my Flutter SDK path is empty. When I download and unzip, the flutter file, and choose its location, it shows "Project location already exists".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Post a screenshot. That can make things much clear.

Comment: I am not allowed to post a picture yet, as I am a new user... So I've added a link to the picture

Comment: try to change name of your project

Answer (score 0):

are you following the flutter steps https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install
if not then try to do the same and you will be fine

Comment: Yes, I did it exactly as instructed on the flutter page.